# Python: как выполнить функцию в определённую дату и время однократно?

Tags: python-3.x, дата, время

Я хочу сделать что-то вроде бота-напоминалки, который напоминает о каком-то событии в заданное время. Пусть есть условная функция:

```
sendMessage('Дедлайн!')
```

Мне надо, чтобы она выполнилась, скажем, 2 апреля в 12:30. Только один раз, а не каждые *X* дней, почему и не подходит модуль `schedule`.

Читал, что люди используют утилиту `at` в Linux, чтобы в заданное время запустить скрипт, но хотелось бы сделать скрипт кроссплатформенным и без дополнительных зависимостей.
То есть основную часть времени запущен бесконечный цикл, в котором (для пользователя) ничего не происходит, а при наступлении заданной даты и времени срабатывает функция `sendMessage`.

Была идея каждые N миллисекунд проверять наступление нужного времени через `datetime`, но, может, есть более изящное и эффективное решение?

Comment: schedule.every().day.at('22:30').do(job_that_executes_once) из документаци по schedule https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#run-a-job-once

Comment: Но это ведь приведёт к тому, что действие будет выполняться в 22:30 каждый день, а не только один раз? Или идея в том, чтобы после действия его отменять?

Comment: Run a job once из документаций да и проверит можно

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрел. Это работает, но остаётся актуальным вопрос с определением конкретной даты. Насколько мне удалось понять, функция `at()` принимает  только время в формате `hh:mm:ss`, но это не сработает, ессли событие должно наступить, скажем, через несколько дней в это время (`dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm`)

Comment: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#run-a-job-every-x-minute https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#example

Comment: until() максимальный параметр год-месяц-день-час-минут-секунд